# WPF: Bind to property of a parent element

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, styles

I'm using a `DataGrid` and would like to introduce a style trigger for cells that sets the background color of the cell depending on the column's `IsReadOnly` property. I think there is some way to get from the cell level to the column level using [`RelativeSource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.relativesource(v=vs.110).aspx) (navigating all the way up to grid and from there back down to the column), but I cannot figure out the exact path to use.

Comment: Maybe try {Binding (DataGridTemplateColumn.IsReadOnly),RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGridTemplateColumn}}} ? Not quite sure since I don´t know your XAML structure. Maybe better post what you´ve got so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the following code inside your DataGrid :

```
<DataGrid.CellStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
        <Style.Triggers>
             <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsReadOnly, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self} }"
                          Value="True">
                 <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
             </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.CellStyle>
```